# I have 2 json how can I decode them with 1 struct?

Tags: json, swift, decode

I have two JSON objects that are similar and their only difference is `joined_user`. In the second `joined_user` is `[]`. I would like to decode them using one struct, how can I do this?

This is my first JSON object

```
{
  "joined_user":[
    {
      "_id":"5c72c03cd1c32313908845d8"
    },
    {
      "_id":"5c72c14ad1c32313908845db"
    }
  ],
  "allRooms":[
    {
      "Capacity":{
        "Free":10,
        "Total":10
      },
      "Finished":false,
      "Pic":"http://192.168.1.101:2525/icon.png",
      "_id":"5c72bf3fd1c32313908845d6",
      "Coin_input":10,
      "Award_money":100000,
      "Award_coin":100,
      "Match_time":"1551551483",
      "Winner_number":1
    },
    {
      "Capacity":{
        "Free":20,
        "Total":20
      },
      "Finished":false,
      "Pic":"http://192.168.1.101:2525/icon.png",
      "_id":"5c72bf58d1c32313908845d7",
      "Coin_input":20,
      "Award_money":200000,
      "Award_coin":200,
      "Match_time":"1551551483",
      "Winner_number":1
    },
    {
      "Capacity":{
        "Free":9,
        "Total":10
      },
      "Finished":false,
      "Pic":"http://192.168.1.101:2525/icon.png",
      "_id":"5c72c03cd1c32313908845d8",
      "Coin_input":100,
      "Award_money":100000,
      "Award_coin":1000,
      "Match_time":"1551551483",
      "Winner_number":1
    },
    {
      "Capacity":{
        "Free":20,
        "Total":20
      },
      "Finished":false,
      "Pic":"http://192.168.1.101:2525/icon.png",
      "_id":"5c72c066d1c32313908845d9",
      "Coin_input":101,
      "Award_money":200000,
      "Award_coin":2000,
      "Match_time":"1551551483",
      "Winner_number":1
    },
    {
      "Capacity":{
        "Free":9209269,
        "Total":10000000
      },
      "Finished":true,
      "Pic":"http://192.168.1.101:2525/icon.png",
      "_id":"5c72c14ad1c32313908845db",
      "Coin_input":12,
      "Award_money":50000,
      "Award_coin":500,
      "Match_time":"1551540600",
      "Winner_number":1
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is my second JSON object

```
{
  "joined_user":"[]",
  "allRooms":[
    {
      "Capacity":{
        "Free":44,
        "Total":100
      },
      "Finished":false,
      "Pic":"www",
      "_id":"5c73c1666f39db1de8977fd9",
      "Coin_input":10,
      "Award_money":10000,
      "Award_coin":1000,
      "Match_time":"9",
      "Winner_number":2
    },
    {
      "Capacity":{
        "Free":9999,
        "Total":9999
      },
      "Finished":false,
      "Pic":"129",
      "_id":"5c7535a56f39db1de897802d",
      "Coin_input":9,
      "Award_money":99999,
      "Award_coin":999,
      "Match_time":"9",
      "Winner_number":9
    },
    {
      "Capacity":{
        "Free":9999,
        "Total":9999
      },
      "Finished":false,
      "Pic":"129",
      "_id":"5c7535a66f39db1de897802e",
      "Coin_input":9,
      "Award_money":99999,
      "Award_coin":999,
      "Match_time":"9",
      "Winner_number":9
    },
    {
      "Capacity":{
        "Free":9999,
        "Total":9999
      },
      "Finished":false,
      "Pic":"129",
      "_id":"5c7535a86f39db1de897802f",
      "Coin_input":9,
      "Award_money":99999,
      "Award_coin":999,
      "Match_time":"9",
      "Winner_number":9
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Make joineduser optional in your struct

Answer (score 1):

This an array of user model

> ```
> "joined_user": [
>    {
>     "_id": "5c72c03cd1c32313908845d8"
>   },
>   {
>     "_id": "5c72c14ad1c32313908845db"
>   }
> ]
> ```

and this is a String

> ```
> "joined_user":"[]"
> ```

To read both you need

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let joinedUser: CombinedRes
    let allRooms: [AllRoom]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case joinedUser = "joined_user"
        case allRooms
    }
}

struct AllRoom: Codable {
    let capacity: Capacity
    let finished: Bool
    let pic, id: String
    let coinInput, awardMoney, awardCoin: Int
    let matchTime: String
    let winnerNumber: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case capacity = "Capacity"
        case finished = "Finished"
        case pic = "Pic"
        case id = "_id"
        case coinInput = "Coin_input"
        case awardMoney = "Award_money"
        case awardCoin = "Award_coin"
        case matchTime = "Match_time"
        case winnerNumber = "Winner_number"
    }
}

struct Capacity: Codable {
    let free, total: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case free = "Free"
        case total = "Total"
    }
}

enum CombinedRes: Codable {
    case joinedUserElementArray([JoinedUserElement])
    case string(String)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode([JoinedUserElement].self) {
            self = .joinedUserElementArray(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(CombinedRes.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for CombinedRes"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .joinedUserElementArray(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .string(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}

struct JoinedUserElement: Codable {
    let id: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "_id"
    }
}
```

but if you can change this

> "joined_user": "[]",

to

> "joined_user": [],

then it would be

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let joinedUser: [JoinedUserElement]
    let allRooms: [AllRoom]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case joinedUser = "joined_user"
        case allRooms
    }
}
```

or

> "joined_user":null,

then would be

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let joinedUser: [JoinedUserElement]?
    let allRooms: [AllRoom]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case joinedUser = "joined_user"
        case allRooms
    }
}
```

---

```
    do {
        let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self,from:data)
        switch(res.joinedUser) {
        case  .joinedUserElementArray( let arr) :
                let ids = arr.map { $0.id }
                print(ids)
        case .string(let str) :
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

You can also write a custom `init` inside `Root` that assigns empty to the array if the received value is a String

Comment: and how can i print the id's in joienduser ??

Comment: if you'll leave the String and array model as said , then you need a Switch and print them inside `.joinedUserElementArray` case

Comment: can you write the code for me please . i want put the id's in array

Comment: @Sh_Khan has answered terrifically already. You should accept his answer in the first place. Please note that StackOverflow is a site which helps you with finding solutions with problems you are seriously struggling with (and show some effort in willingness to solve them yourself). Simply asking others for "doing your work" will not yield great result, especially if you cannot be specific in your request. Please amend your question with what you have learned and ask another one if necessary.